# Install 13.04 on Mac Mini (End 2012)

Tags: 13.04, mac-mini

I am trying to install *Ubuntu 13.04* (the 64-bit Mac variant) onto my Mac Mini.
Thus I shrunk the main MacOSX partition and installed *refind*.
Now I can boot into *rEFInd* and then select the usb stick, but it does not boot due to:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

Sadly I cannot find anyone who tried a recent Mac Mini/Ubuntu version.
How best to debug this issue?

---

**Update 1:**

So I figured maybe *rEFInd* does not provide the necessary driver and installed it again via `install.sh --drivers-all`. Which lead to a WSOD.
Luckily I eventually could get back into restore via *Command* + *R* and am now reinstalling MacOSX.

---

**Update 2:**

After my MacOSX was working again I did:

- installed _rEFIt
- set up my future Ubuntu partition as *FAT*
- booted twice
- booted into Ubuntu Live CD

And that's where the next trouble started. While wireless and graphics work great in *Ubuntu 13.04*, they mount the FAT partition as `/cdrom`, which makes installing on it impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try rEFIt instead  ?

check out http://mabelmzhang.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-guide-for-triple-booting-mac-os.html

rEFIT / Ubuntu 12.04 LTS / Kernel 3.9.x worked for me

Comment: _rEFIt_ seems no longer maintained!? You are talking about a recent Mac Mini with Mountain Lion installed?

Comment: correct. rEFIt is no maintatined. but it's MAC friendly and works.

Comment: I am still missing the Mac Mini model you installed on.

Comment: I got MacMini 6.2 now  with triple boot set up for OSX 10.8.3, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Kernel 3.9.x)  and Windows 7  based on link http://mabelmzhang.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-guide-for-triple-booting-mac-os.html

Comment: I got the late 2012 Mac Mini 6,2 model with the i7 processor running OSX Mountain Lion.  This one => http://store.apple.com/us/configure/MD388LL/A?#hardware

Comment: And why did you use _ubuntu 12.04_ to install?

Comment: since Ubuntu 12.04 has Long-term Supoort ( LTS ) until mid y2017. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS  . needed a stable platform for my Java development  and chose to stay clear from the bleeding-edge and the excess Unity bloatware that come with 12.10 and higher.

Comment: I installed ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso (13-Feb-2013 on http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ )  from a bootable USB .

Comment: here's my install steps   (1) fresh install mountain lion (2) created partitions using the OSX Disk Utility per http://mabelmzhang.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-to-guide-for-triple-booting-mac-os.html    (3) installed rEFIt from OSX; reboot twice  (4) Installed Windows 7 from CD via rEFIt menu  (5) Installed Ubuntu 12.04 from USB via the rEFIt menu  (6) Then upgraded to Kernel 3.9.x to get Wired Network connection working  (7)  Used  'sudo pm-suspend' to work-around low color HDMI video issue. (8) removed Unity bloatware => https://sites.google.com/site/howtomakeubuntu1204notterrible/

Comment: You are right, rEFIt works. Sadly the live cd is a little weird.

Comment: hmm. I didn't use the live CD.

Comment: I followed these instructions to make a bootable USB from the OSX, http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx .  Then I booted Ubuntu 12.04 from the bootable USB off the rEFIt menu.

Comment: Pardon me. but I am curious whether you booted the Live CD off rEFIt menu or by holding down the OPTION key .

Answer (score 0):

- Kernel 3.5.x appears to have issues enabling Wired Ethernet Connection on Mac Mini 2012.
  Upgrade to Kernel 3.9.x fixed the issue.
- Also had low color issue with HDMI graphics.
  work-around: 'sudo pm-suspend'

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat complete guide that I wrote to help you all brave tux users to make the whole Ubuntu/Linux mint installation process a breeze. I try to address all the issues I had with wireless broadcom drivers and power management.

Have a read and post comments if something is not right with the document..

https://theredblacktree.wordpress.com/2013/09/07/installation-guide-for-linux-mint-15-ubuntu-13-04-on-apple-mac-mini-late-2012/